# Dagger 2 examples

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-2

Dagger 2 is around the corner but the available examples wouldn't even compile right off the box, and the documentation is a copy-paste-replace from Dagger 1.

Does anyone have an example of a proper application working on Google's Dagger 2?

Comment: The examples compile fine here. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: There's another one but I'll add an specific example tomorrow. For reference, references in lib project with multiDex but using them in main app project, latest Android Studio, BuildTools 21.1.+

Comment: As for dependencies, dagger-compile is provided, but dagger is compiled, both in the library project.

Comment: The examples are probably fine, but the examples duplicated inside my project setup are not.

Comment: Also, the Dagger_ classes will either not be generated or picked up in the indexes. For similar approaches like Project Lombok a plugin is needed for the editor to understand code generation, but even doing it manually wouldn't come up with results.

Comment: Basically I was after this example https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020 updated to Dagger2.

Comment: See: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/pull/42 for an initial Dagger 2 version.

Comment: apt instead of provided for the -compiler module. Noted.

Comment: This example works too https://github.com/gk5885/dagger-android-sample

Comment: So the only way to make generated Dagger_ classes correctly visible from IDE point of view it needs some kind of plugin? By default IDE (Android Studio, for example) unable to correctly work with Deggar_ classes?

Comment: Same as with Lombok Plugin, apparently yes.

Comment: What would you be looking for in an accepted answer to this question? I see some basic examples from the answers below. Are you looking for more clarity, larger apps?

Comment: Either option is equally good, they take different approaches to it, and also from the original example. I don't have the heart to just choose one as correct.

Comment: Check this Reddit link. Maybe that will be helpful for you.
https://redd.it/8az1wv

Comment: See the simplest dagger 2 sample with the latest version  https://github.com/rkandoroidrepo/android-dagger2-example.

Answer (score 27):

I've just published sample app based on Gradle which integrates Dagger2, retrolambda, butterknife and lombok. You can find it here: https://github.com/mgrzechocinski/dagger2-example.

Hope it would help :)

Comment: Nice! Just beware of Lombok and general annotation processors on Multidex applications, they're known to have major bugs in Dalvik.

Comment: It would be really great if you could write up a blog post about your Demo. For newbies, it is really hard to related most of the implementations with the explanation from http://google.github.io/dagger/.

Comment: Thanks for the sample you shared. got me going. Much better than the sample that google folks shared.

Comment: The example has a lot of extra frameworks/libraries that make the code more verbose and confuse those who are just trying to pickup dagger 2.

Comment: What's up with have a separate .Activity and .Application? I've never seen that practice before. Could be important to learn.

Answer (score 20):

I've just ported [u2020-mvp](https://github.com/LiveTyping/u2020-mvp) app to Dagger 2. We use it as our sandbox app. Dagger 2 has nice implementation of scopes by the way. Components are really big deal. 
And it is based on [u2021](https://github.com/cgruber/u2020/tree/dagger2) made by Christian Gruber. You can check that as well.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Why do you have two repositories{} sections in your build.gradle file?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, one is buildscript repositories for apt gradle plugin, the second is for project dependencies. They differ from the root one, so they has to overriden.

Comment: Quite confusing to have multiple ones, violates the DRY principle.

Comment: It does. Do not like it myself. The main reason of separating repositories was the case when you have multiple subprojects (e.g. libraries, data layer). Considering them full repositories list in root file is redundant. However, for example purposes better to keep them all in root file. Will fix that when I have time. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 19):

For anyone looking for a simple and straightforward way to just build a Dagger 2 project on Gradle/Android Studio, check out https://github.com/bytehala/dagger2-gradle-quickstart

In the [commit messages](https://github.com/bytehala/dagger2-gradle-quickstart/commits/master), I also enumerate the steps to convert a fully functioning project to Dagger 2.

> The target audience for this project is anyone who has no experience with dependency injection.

No other library besides Butterknife is used.

**WARNING**
The aim of this sample project is simplicity, not completeness.
Only the following features were used:

- @Module
- @Component
- @Injects
- @Provides
- @Singleton

Topics such as scopes, submodules, etc are left as an exercise.

Comment: I'd recommend to remove all IntelliJ dependencies like .iml files

Comment: Really? I didn't know that had to be done. I figured the .gitignore given by AS was enough. LOL

I'll do as you recommend in the morning, I promise. Any other files I should remove from git?

Comment: Everything else is okay. .iml files and .idea folder tend to have local paths plus some naughty stuff with gradle versioning if you're using wildcard :+ version numbers.

Answer (score 3):

CoffeeMaker sample without android: https://github.com/yongjhih/dagger2-sample

Steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/yongjhih/dagger2-sample
cd dagger2-sample
./gradlew execute
```

Comment: Great finding, although I never found the Coffee Maker sample enlightening.

Comment: You should add arbitrary injection somewhere, the example is incomplete without it.

Comment: Thanks. The sample is imported from official https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee .

You can see injections in Thermosiphon and CoffeeMaker.

Comment: Personally, I found Coffe Maker example confusing. It lacks a lot of information, i.e.: there is no need of using modules in simple cases (when You can provide class objects by yourself jest annotating class constructor with `@Inject` annotation).